# Cantor's diagonal argument: Prove that $|A|<|A^{\Bbb N}|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq...$ be a raising series of sets such that $\forall n\in \Bbb N \ |A_n|\lt |A_{n+1}|$. We mark $A$ as $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$. Prove that $|A|<|A^{\Bbb N}|$

I've shown that $|A|\le|A^{\Bbb N}|$ since $f:A\rightarrow A^{\Bbb N}$ defined by $f(a)=(a,a,a,...)$ is an injection. I've considered for the sake of contradiction that $|A|=|A^{\Bbb N}|$ and tried to use Cantor's diagonal argument in order to get contradiction, but I got stuck. Thanks

Comment: Do you hvae some reason to think this is true?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich : yes, it's a question from a test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Asaf points out, Konig's Theorem applies here. It states (Jech, *Set Theory*, Millenium Edition, Theorem 5.10):

> If $\kappa_i < \lambda_i$ for all $i \in I$, then
>   $$
> \sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i < \prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i. \tag{Konig}
> $$

Take $I = \Bbb N$, and for all $n\in I$, $\kappa_n = \lvert A_n\rvert$, $\lambda_n = \lvert A \rvert$. Then by (Konig),
$$\begin{align}
\lvert A \rvert & = \sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i \\
                & < \prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i \tag{by Konig's Theorem} \\
                & = \lvert A \rvert^{\lvert \Bbb N \rvert} \\
                & = \lvert A ^{\Bbb N} \rvert.
\end{align}$$

Note that Cantor's Theorem is an easy consequence of Konig's Theorem (Jech, Corollary 5.11): take $I = \Bbb N$, and $\kappa_i = 1, \lambda_i = 2$ for $i\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: There's nothing missing; it essentially says that the cofinality of $|A|$ is countable. Now apply Koenig's theorem.

Comment: if A is countable than $|A|=\aleph_0\lt |A^{\Bbb N}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ but why A is countable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Umm, yes quite true. Perhaps you should post that as an answer? so I can delete this ?:)

Comment: I'll pass, feel free to take this one.

Comment: @guest If all the $A_n$ are countable then $A$ is a countable union of countable sets, thus countable. As Asaf points out, though, in any case the assumptions guarantee that $A$ has countable *cofinality* — $cof(\lvert A\rvert) = \omega$ — so Konig's theorem (on infinite sums and products in cardinal arithmetic) applies.